# tutorial for deriving solar insolation estimates from high resolution Digital surface model

Tags: grass-gis

I want to estimate solar insolation using grass gis. I have a high resolution DSM generated from Large Format Digital camera.Being a novice in this field i Would like to have a tutorial and steps to derive the solar estimates.Also I would like to estimate solar radiation on 3d building roof tops.

Answer (score 3):

The module to calculate insolation estimates is [r.sun](http://grass.osgeo.org/grass70/manuals/r.sun.html). There is a related Wiki page available at: http://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/R.sun

In order to simplify accumulated calculations, see these two [addons](http://grass.osgeo.org/grass70/manuals/addons/):

- r.sun.daily: Runs r.sun for multiple days in loop (mode 2)
- r.sun.hourly: Runs r.sun in loop for given time range (mode 1)

Be sure to include the cast shadows, i.e. you need to select the area of computation ([computational region](http://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/Computational_region)) large enough.